# Chrome Extension: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

This is my first time fiddling with a Chrome extension and it should be pretty simple, but I can't quite get all the pieces to fit together. Overall my goal is that whenever a new tab is opened matching part of a URL (i.e. `https://somewhere.com/script.php?id=*`) it will put that tab in a new group, name that group the title of the page, and collapse the group.

The relevant code is pretty simple, and works when I run it by clicking the extension button:

```js
const group = await chrome.tabs.group( { "tabIds" :  tab.id } );
await chrome.tabGroups.update(group, { title: tab.title, "collapsed": true });
```

However, I would like it to just run automatically whenever a new tab is opened. I am attempting to add a listener to fire the code, but getting an `Unexpected reserved word` error on `await`. Removing the two `await`s resolves the error, but the code doesn't work then. At least, it's not being called from the event.

Here is my code. Note that I originally just used an anonymous function, but created a separate function just to see if that made a difference:

```js
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(group_tabs(tab));

function group_tabs(tab){
  if (tab.url.indexOf('https://myurl.com/instances.php?account_id=') != -1) {
    const group = await chrome.tabs.group( { "tabIds" :  tab.id } );
    await chrome.tabGroups.update(group, { title: tab.title, "collapsed": true });
  }
};
```

Bonus points if anyone can explain how to run this code without clicking on the extension icon.

Here are the complete contents of the original `popup.js` file shamelessly stolen from the Google Developers git repo:

```js
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(group_tabs(tab));

function group_tabs(tab){
  if (tab.url.indexOf('https://wupgrade.wsysnet.com/cloud_support/dashboard/instances.php?account_id=') != -1) {
    const group = await chrome.tabs.group( { "tabIds" :  tab.id } );
    await chrome.tabGroups.update(group, { title: tab.title, "collapsed": true });
  }
};

const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({
  url: [
    'https://wupgrade.wsysnet.com/cloud_support/dashboard/instances.php?account_id=*'
  ]
});

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator
const collator = new Intl.Collator();
tabs.sort((a, b) => collator.compare(a.title, b.title));

const template = document.getElementById('li_template');
const elements = new Set();
for (const tab of tabs) {
  const element = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);

  const title = tab.title.split('-')[0].trim();
  const pathname = new URL(tab.url).pathname.slice('/docs'.length);

  element.querySelector('.title').textContent = title;
  element.querySelector('.pathname').textContent = pathname;
  element.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    // need to focus window as well as the active tab
    await chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
    await chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, { focused: true });
  });
    const group = await chrome.tabs.group( { "tabIds" :  tab.id } );
    await chrome.tabGroups.update(group, { title: tab.title, "collapsed": true });
  elements.add(element);
}
document.querySelector('ul').append(...elements);

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const tabIds = tabs.map(({ id }) => id);
  if (tabIds.length) {
    const group = await chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds });
    await chrome.tabGroups.update(group, { title: 'DOCS' });
  }
});
```

The way it initially worked was when you click the extension, any tab that matched the URL would be put into its own collapsed group and named accordingly. That was a major advance for me, but the problem came when I had some groups already open, opened more, and then clicked the icon. It would remove any tabs with matching URLs from the existing groups, and put them into a new group leaving the other tabs in the old group.

I don't see a way to check if a tab is already in a group and having this just run automatically on new tabs would be a much better solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try adding `async` before `function group_tabs(tab)` and add the two `await` keywords back. It also seem that the code `const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({...` should be wrapped into some function and executed after a tab is created.